# How to use transparency to see recycler view item (from behind of another layout) when scrolling

Tags: android, transparency, android-recyclerview

I want to see RecyclerView items when scrolling it from behind of top layout     ( LinearLayout with top id).
I can see the scroll bar from behind but recyclerview item , no .

please help.

this is my xml layout :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:alpha="0.25"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_950"
        android:id="@+id/btn_ketabdonUpdate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="yyyyy"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_950"
        android:id="@+id/btn_ketabdonFilter"
        android:text="xxxxx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:id="@+id/rv_fragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />
 </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```